# How to draw the routes between current location and another location

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

In my app I have to show the route between current Location and specified client Location using Map kit framework.

Comment: I tried but not working for me

Comment: Can you show your code and tell us what is not working in it?

Comment: locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: How can i print the current location longitude and Lattitude in NSLog using this code

Comment: Have you implemented the `CLLocationManager` delegate methods? That will give you the current location (or change in location).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47021/discussion-between-anupama-and-amar)

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Maps..

We can have route using below code

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?//saddr=Current+Location&daddr=42.889,-77.2803"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

Hope it helps..